# Symfony 3.3.9 - problems with displaying relations

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have troubles with displaying relations between entities.
I have the following entities:
Category
Seminar
Topic

There is a ManyToOne between Seminar and Category (each seminar belongs to exact one category) and a ManyToMany between Seminar and Topic (each seminar can have several topics). The relations are working because the modification of seminars works like a charm.

Now I want to display a list based on topics and categories:

Topic
-> Category
   -> Seminar

As you could imagine it is no problem to iterate over the topics to get all seminars but I want to iterate over the topics to show a list of all used categories for the seminars with this specific topic. 
I have no clue on how to create the needed query (or whatever is needed). I have a good idea how it would look like in pure SQL but not with doctrine.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Sebastian

UPDATE:
The output should be a stacked list of DIVs or similar as a navigation (for easier writing shown with lists):

```
<ul>
  <li class="topic">Topic1
    <ul class="category">Category3(because 1 and 2 do not contain seminars with this topic)
      <li>Seminar 17</li>
      <li>Seminar 31</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="topic">Topic3 (because there are no seminars with Topic2)
    <ul class="category">Category3
      <li>Seminar 8</li>
      <li>Seminar 24</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In SQL I would do something like (I do not show the ManyToMany between topics and seminars for easier writing and understanding):

```
select t.*, c.*, s.* 
    from Topics t 
        inner join seminars s on t.id=s.topicId
        inner join categories c on c.id=s.categoryId
    order by t.id, c.id, s.id
```

and of course I have to deal with the equal topics and categories during rendering.

Comment: can you add a sample of the html you want to have? it's hard to really understand how the output should looks. it can change our answer about the data structure.

Comment: If you understand how to achieve that with pure SQL - please show us that SQL, and we will help you do the same in Doctrine.

Comment: Please see my update in the question